# Can a decorator in the Decorator Pattern be used to add additional methods?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a class, called Sprite:

```
public abstract class Sprite
{
    protected Texture2D Image { get; set; }
    protected Vector2 position;

    public Sprite(Texture2D image, Vector2 position)
    {
        Image = image;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch imageBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Image, position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Inheriting from it is AnimatedSprite:

```
public abstract class AnimatedSprite : Sprite
{
    protected Point SheetSize          { get; set; }
    protected Point CurrentFrame       { get; set; }
    protected Point FrameSize          { get; set; }
    protected int MillisecondsPerFrame { get; set; }
    protected int TimeSinceLastFrame   { get; set; }

    public AnimatedSprite(Point sheetSize, Point currentFrame, Point frameSize,
        int millisecondsPerFrame, int timeSinceLastFrame, Texture2D image, Vector2 position)
        : base(image, position)
    {
        SheetSize    = sheetSize;
        CurrentFrame = currentFrame;
        FrameSize    = frameSize;
        MillisecondsPerFrame = millisecondsPerFrame;
        TimeSinceLastFrame   = timeSinceLastFrame;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Image, position,
            new Rectangle(CurrentFrame.X * FrameSize.X,
                CurrentFrame.Y * FrameSize.Y,
                FrameSize.X, FrameSize.Y), Color.White);
    }
}
```

Inhereting from *that* is Invader:

```
public class Invader : AnimatedSprite
{
    public Invader(Point sheetSize, Point currentFrame, Point frameSize,
        int millisecondsPerFrame, int timeSinceLastFrame, Texture2D image, Vector2 position)
        : base(sheetSize, currentFrame, frameSize, millisecondsPerFrame, timeSinceLastFrame,
        image, position)
    {

    }
}
```

I think this would be a good one to implement the decorator pattern. The problem is that in most examples of the decorator pattern I see a method from the root abstract class being inherited by the decorater, and no additional things, which I do have.

Can I use the decorator pattern here, and can I add additional stuff to the abstract AnimatedSprite class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators decorate objects that implement the Component interface.  In that sense, your subclasses don't decorate 'root' objects; they don't aggregate the interface, but inherit it (Invader < AnimatedSprite < Sprite ).

So the pattern matching this scenario is not Decorator.  It's basic Specialization as far as I can tell...

Things are not being added because the *user* of the Component interface sees no more than the interface.  You can only partly *change* the implementation of the decorated Component.

Could you *use* decorator?  I guess you could, to add a 'glow', for instance:

```
public class GlowingSprite : Sprite {
    private Sprite sprite;
    public override void Draw( SpriteBatch imageBatch ) {
       sprite.Draw(imageBatch); 

       // decoration happens vvv
       imageBatch.Overlay( GlowingOval, sprite.position ); //  
    }
}
```

Comment: I know - but I thought it might be a good candidate for the Decorator pattern. Or is it?

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. What I have is not a Decorator pattern because nothing happens to the Sprite (imageBatch) itself.